# How do i put square parentheses around an input in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and my professor gave us the assignment to write different functions. Writing the function is easy but he gave us examples of what the output should be and it kind of threw me off.

```
>>> average([])
0.0
>>> average([1.0])
1.0
>>> average([5.0, 10.0, 20.0])
11.666666666666666
```

This was the example. How can I place square brackets around my input like that?

Comment: that looks like a list def average(listInput): where inputList is of type list. inputList=[]

Comment: Square brackets are the way you type a list as a literal. Your application should put all the inputs into a list.

Comment: [Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Answer (score 1):

```
def average(inputlist)
    return sum(inputlist)/len(inputlist)
```

If you do this

```
average([2, 4, 5])
```

The function will know you are passing a list parameter since python is a dynamically typed language, that is - the type of the parameter inputlist will be determined at runtime.

Alternatively, you could just define your list first, then pass it to the function like this.

```
inputValues = [2, 4, 5]
average(inputValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

Square parenthesis in python signify that your function is taking in an list as one of it's arguments.

You would take multiple inputs and append them to a list, which later you would input in the function.

Therefore your code will look like this:

```
def average(listOfNumbers):
    total = sum(listOfNumbers)
    return float(total)/len(listOfNumbers)

numOfInputs = int(input("Number of inputs: "))
numbers = []
for i in range(numOfInputs):
    numbers.append(int(input("Enter Number: ")))
print(average(numbers))
```

Comment: Please correct “signify that your function is taking in an array”, and change 'array' to 'list'.  These are *very* different things in Python.

Answer (score 0):

That means that your function has to take a list as an input. Therefore, you should assume your function is like below:

```py
      def average(input): 
          # input looks like [0,5,6]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Suggestion: Change the name of the `input` variable to something else, as it’s (confusing) and currently overwriting the builtin function.

Comment: `an array` - Not an array, a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Answer (score 0):

Create a list and then append your inputs to the list and then apply the function
Try this code:

```
nums = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    nums.append(int(input()))
average(nums)
```

This above code will take an input `n`  and then it takes `n` input numbers and then applies the average (any mathematical function).

Answer (score 0):

```
def average(*args):
    for i in args:
        return sum(i)/len(i)
    
print(average([42,67,23,89]))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.